# QgsVectorLayer Line layer in memory, layer source could not be found PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I'm at a loss for what I could be missing here

```
    self.curve_layer = QgsVectorLayer("line?crs=epsg:4326", "curves", "memory")
    feats = []
    xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(102008), QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326), QgsProject.instance())
    for item in result:
        feature = QgsFeature()
        geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(item)
        geom.transform(xform)
        feature.setGeometry(geom)
        feats.append(feature)
    self.curve_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures(feats)
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.curve_layer)
```

the result variable is a list of linestrings:
[image]

result is this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a invalid layer:

```
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer("line?crs=EPSG:4326", "curves1", "memory") #Invalid
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=EPSG:4326", "curves2", "memory") #Valid

for layer in [layer1, layer2]:
    print(layer.isValid())
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
    
#False
#True
```

[image]

Comment: Ah facepalm, thank you friend.